# PS/2 keyboard with (USB to PS/2 conertor) not working

Tags: keyboard

I have an old PS/2 keyboard. So i bouht a PS/2 to USB convertor to connect it to my HP laptop(bought last month). It isn't working. The thing is, when i use commands like "lsusb" and "lsinput" it shows my keyboard as a barcode reader.
The same thing happens in my windows 10 system too. But I have connected a keyboard only.

Also, all the 3 LEDs light up in my keyboard, once I connect them to my laptop.

Is there a problem with the connector cable or keyboard itself or any "drivers" required to install it???

Comment: Please run `lsusb`, and [edit] your question to add the output from that command.

Comment: i've never needed any drivers for my model m (ps/2) keyboards.  usb contains four pins; 2 for data, 2 for power - leds prove power lines work.  i plugged in a usb->ps2 convertor into [ub16.04] thinkpad & diff'd `lsusb;lsinput` output before & after and 'barcode reader' appears for convertor itself (also there on this workstation which has conv for its model m kbd).  when I plugged in a model.m [ps2] keyboard into thinkpad there was nothing showing extra in `lsusb;lsinput` when diff'd with convertor alone.  but my ps2 keyboard worked. i suspect your convertor (i've had issues with them before)

Comment: correction: suspect issues with your converter or keyboard